# vSphere with VMWare ESXi 5.1 VMRC Error

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I've rebooted my dedicated server entirely. I powered on the VM's and then I noticed when trying to enter the console, I got the blow error (see image):

[image]

I've tried uninstalling vSphere completely. I've also reinstalled VMWare ESXi as my dedi's main OS as well, and none of those have worked. It happens right after I create a VM and power it on and visit the "console" setting.

HOWEVER, it works when my friend connects to the dedi on his vSphere. But then it'll eventually do it again where it doesn't work for me.

What could cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: Lots and lots of hits in Google, also in the VMware KB. What have you tried already?

Comment: What do you mean? I've explained what solutions in troubleshooting I've tried. I'm now stumped.

Comment: So, anything in the client's logfiles?

Comment: @Marki, it happens even when first creating a brand new VM.

Comment: If you are too stubborn to take a look at the logs of the client what shall I say?

Comment: As per the SF FAQ you need to show a basic willing of troubleeshooting if you not willing then we cannot help. The logs say alot

Comment: You're not even answering properly. "Look at the logs" isn't very helpful. Specify where at, maybe? I'm new to this.

Comment: Being more specific of where these logs are located? There's loads of logs.

Comment: The [vSphere client logs themselves](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.monitoring.doc%2FGUID-37E4F352-5F1D-4881-938D-6DE3C003A3F7.html) are located in `C:\Documents and Settings\[user_name]\Local Settings\Application Data\vpx\`

Comment: Ok, this is ESXi 5.1 and you're connecting using the VSphere Client (not the web interface). Is there a Vcenter Server involved? In any case, on my (Win7) PC the VSphere Client (4.1) logs are at C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\VMware\vpx. There's actually not that many. There are only viclient-xxx files here. Let me just say that if you're administrating a virtual environment you should have basic troubleshooting skills...

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this do the following.

1. Close all vSphere Client sessions.
2. Open Windows Task Manager.
3. Search for any vmware-vmrc.exe processes and end the process.
4. Start the vSphere Client

Comment: Yeah that's VMware KB2032016. If that's really the problem the user should really start to learn using Google.